# Value Error on Dask DataFrames

Tags: dask

I am using dask to read a csv file. However, i couldn't apply or compute any operation on it because of this error:

Do you have ideas what is this error all about and how to fix it?[image]

Comment: Can you help by providing an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @MRocklin, thank you so much for always helping. I find the solution to the problem through your answer to this post: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1166

Comment: @MRocklin, the error comes from inferring the data types so what I did is let pandas first read the csv file, get the correct dtype and use this for dask read_csv. However, this might not be always helpful when we deal with bigger sets of data.

Comment: If you solved your problem, you could consider writing out a full solution below, as a help to other people, and accepting your own answer. On the other hand, if you think this question is not useful to anyone, you might consider deleting it.

Comment: @mdurant, sorry for the late reply. I have my answer shown below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On reading csv file in dask, errors comes in upon not recognizing the correct dtype of columns.

For example, we read a csv file using dask as follows:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('\data\file.txt', sep='\t', header='infer')
```

This prompts the error mentioned above.

To solve this problem, as suggested by @mrocklin on this comment, https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1166, we need to determine the dtype of the columns. We can do this by reading the csv file in pandas and identify the data type and pass that as argument in reading csv using dask.

```
df_pd = pd.read_csv('\data\file.txt', sep='\t', header='infer')
dt = df_pd.dtypes.to_dict()
df = dd.read_csv('\data\file.txt', sep='\t', header='infer', dtype=dt)
```